# Datos repetidos C++ archivo.txt

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++

El programa se encarga de leer un archivo.txt desde la tercera posición, y crear una lista doble, usando todos los numeros enteros que encuentre, pero necesito lograr que omita los datos cuando se repitan, como podría lograr esto sin usar arreglos, ya que tiene que poder aceptar un texto con una cantidad indefinida de valores.

```
void leermostrar(){ //Leer mostrar lista 

ifstream archivo;
string texto;
archivo.open("entrada.txt",ios::in);
if(archivo.fail()){
    cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
archivo>>a; // primer dato
archivo.seekg(3);
while(!archivo.eof()){
    p=(nodo *) malloc (sizeof(struct nodo));
    archivo>>p->n;
    if(cab==NULL){
        p->ant=p->sig=NULL;
        cab=ult=p;  
     }
    else{
        p->sig=cab;
        p->ant=NULL;
        cab->ant=p;
        cab=p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

- Has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) e incluso usas herramientas del lenguaje, pero después usas `malloc` para reservar memoria y antepones `struct` a los tipos para crearlos.
- Hablas de una lista doble (¿doblemente enlazada?) de la que no muestras implementación alguna.
- Hablas de un objeto lista, pero programas con funciones libres, no con funciones del objeto.
- Los flujos de entrada de datos desde archivo (`i`nput `f`ile `stream`) son por definición de entrada, así que no hay que abrirlos con `std::ios::in`.
- Te faltan llaves de cierre, declaras variables que no usas y usas variables que no están declaradas.
- No puedes condicionar la lectura de datos a la detección de `eof`, porque la marca de final de archivo se obtiene después de la lectura.

Si realmente tu código es C++, debería tener este aspecto:

```
void leermostrar(){ //Leer mostrar lista 

    using namespace std;

    if (ifstream archivo{"entrada.txt"})
    {
        nodo *n = new nodo;

        // Aquí la lógica de lectura
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Si quieres evitar leer datos repetidos tienes que poder comprobar si un dato ya existe en la lista y en caso de existir, evitar guardarlo:

```
void leermostrar(){ //Leer mostrar lista 

    using namespace std;

    if (ifstream archivo{"entrada.txt"})
    {
        nodo *n = new nodo;

        // Aquí la lógica de lectura
        int dato{};

        while (archivo >> dato)
        {
            if (/* el dato ya está guardado en la lista */)
            {
                cout << "El dato " << dato << " ya esta guardado\n";
            }
            else
            {
                    // Guardar.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No se pudo abrir el archivo" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```